# flex 3 server.error.request sending webservice

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a .net webservice which I invoke in flex and then I have form where I insert a new post  to the table through another method in the webservice. 
But when I try to insert the method, flex generates an error:

> [RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request
>   error" 
>   faultCode="Server.Error.Request"
>   faultDetail="Error:  [IOErrorEvent
>   type="ioError" bubbles=false
>   cancelable=false  eventPhase=2
>   text="Error #2032: Stream Error.  URL:
>   http://localhost:xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx.asmx"].
>   URL:
>   http://localhost:xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.asmx"]

But the method works fine and the post is added to the database. That's little confusing because I really don't know what Flex is doing. And how about having multiple methods in the .NET webservice, does it matter? Or trying to call the same URL with different webservice calls in flex.

Anyone who knows?

Answer (score 0):

copy and paste "http://localhost:xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx.asmx" into your browser and make sure you can view that page...

also make sure your wsdl parameter looks like this:
wsdl="http://localhost:xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx.asmx?wsdl"